# How to write results from simulate to a csv file and import them for parmest

Tags: pyomo

I am new with Pyomo, and I am starting with some examples available. One of the applications I would like to handle with Pyomo is parameter estimation especially from DAE models.

My questions are:

1. how to save the data obtained from a simulation (using the Simulator) to a .csv file? Here, data are the time instants and the solution profiles;
2. how to import a .csv file for parameter estimation?
   Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please provide a [example] in accordance with the [ask] guidelines of the [help]. See the [tour] for a general intro to how things are run here.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question can be answered by reading the docs